# How can I change the width of a geom_xspline() in R? (ggplot / ggalt)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geom

I am trying to plot a smoothed trendline but for various reasons I cannot use geom_smooth() to achieve my goal.

The data is in the format:

| time | value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 124 | 1 |
| 1 | 452 | 2 |
| 2 | 49 | 1 |
| 2 | 453 | 2 |
| 3 | 788 | 1 |
| 3 | 652 | 2 |
| 4 | 356 | 1 |
| 4 | 452 | 2 |

The code I have so far is:

```
ggplot(data, 
       aes(x = time,
           y = value,
           color = Group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_xspline() +
  theme(line = element_line(linewidth = 1))
```

This does not change the width of the geom_xspline(). Neither does `geom_xspline(size = 2)` or

```
ggplot(data, 
       aes(x = time,
           y = value,
           color = Group,
           size = 2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_xspline()
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the geom_smooth method:

```
ggplot(data , aes(x = time, y = value ,color = as.factor(Group)))  + 
 geom_point() + 
 geom_smooth(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", se = FALSE, lwd=1, formula = 
 'y~x')
```

Note: As @swediot above mentioned,  use as.factor(Group)

For geom_smooth , select a method,  'lm' or 'loess' , se = True or false for confidence interval.

lwd = 1 for linewidth , and then the formula that you want the line to use.

Check out geom_smooth on here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't use geom_smooth since I need to force the fitted line to go through all of the datapoints in the dataset.

Comment: library(ggalt)

ggplot(data , aes(x = time, y = value ,color = as.factor(group)))  + 
  geom_point() + geom_xspline() + aes(lwd = 2)

Comment: Change aes(lwd = 2) depending on your line width

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggalt)

ggplot(data , aes(x = time, y = value ,color = as.factor(group)))  + 
geom_point() + 
geom_xspline() + 
aes(lwd = 2)
```

Change aes(lwd = 2) depending on your line width

Hope this helps